# search form display no result

Tags: search, forms

i create a searchform in my footer.php

```
    <div id="cd-search" class="cd-search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <input type="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Search...">
        <input type="submit" value="query">
    </form>
</div>
```

and my search.php like this

```
<?php
```

/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages.
 *
 * @package Shape
 * @since Shape 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

```
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php the_title(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

but when i type something it shows nothing and page just refreshing 
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in your `footer.php` :

```
<div id="cd-search" class="cd-search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <input type="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Search..." name="s" id="s" >
        <input type="submit" value="query">
    </form>
</div>
```

You are missing `name="s" id="s"` which is needed to add in terms of getting search term.

After search you will see that name in your URL parameter something like : `yoursite.com/?s=searched`

Comment: Yes, see edited.